# Click coordinates in Firefox toolbar button

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

I want to get the click coordinates from the toolbar icon in my Firefox extension.

The code I am using is given below:
`//Toolbar code`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>                 
<overlay id="myext-toolbar-Overlay"
xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://myext/skin/myextToolbarButton.css" type="text/css"?>

<script src="chrome://myext/content/myextExtension.js" type="application/x-javascript" />

<toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
    <toolbarbutton id="myext-button" class="toolbarbutton-1"
      label="Button"
      tooltiptext="Clip Web Page"
      oncommand="myextExtension.showPopup(event);" >
    </toolbarbutton>
</toolbarpalette>

</overlay>
```

On clicking the toolbar icon a popup is displayed. I want to display the popup at the position where the toolbar icon was clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `command` event is not a mouse event, it can be triggered by different means (mouse and keyboard being the most common ones) so you cannot get the mouse position here. You could define a handler for the `click` event, remember `event.screenX`/`event.screenY` there and use these in your `command` event handler then if they are available. But it is probably better to add a [`popup` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Attribute/popup) to your button and let the system deal with it. Or just use [`<toolbarbutton type="menu">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/toolbarbutton#a-toolbarbutton.type).

Comment: Thanks :) I took the first approach. That is defining a click handler for the toolbar button and storing the coordinates there. It seems to be working. However, does the click event always come before the command event is triggered?

Comment: @quad_damage: If the `command` event is triggered by mouse - yes.